# CSS background-image problem

Tags: css, layout, html

I am writing `<div id="my_div"> Hello </div>` and when I put

```
#my_div
{
    background-image:url(../images/material_bot.png)
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

then the background does not figure, but when I remove the `background-repeat: no-repeat;` the I see the background image repeating to right and down.

What is the problem?

Comment: You're missing the `;` from the end of the first line, so your CSS won't get read correctly. See if adding the semi-colon at the end of the first line fixes it.

Comment: What does "the background does not figure" mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the ; from the end of the first line, so your CSS won't get read correctly. See if adding the semi-colon at the end of the first line fixes it.

```
#my_div
{
    background-image:url(../images/material_bot.png); /* <-- Semicolon added here */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```